# Why autocomplete MaterializeCSS not working?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, materialize

I'm trying to make Web app using Google Apps Script. Webapp needs to search within google sheet and let users choose an entry from google sheet. When the line is chosen it will open a new editing form. I can't figure out why autocomplete is not working. Deleted everything but autocomplete part because StackOverflow complains about questions being mostly code. Please help. Here is my code:

`page.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <?!= include("page-css"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s9">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
          <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
          <label for="autocomplete-input">Search for address</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <?!= include("page-js"); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

`page-js.html`

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateWords).getWords();
  }
  function populateWords(words){
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
    var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, {
       data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": null,
        }
     });
  }
</script>
```

`Code.gs`

```
function doGet(e){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Const_Sources")
    var list = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();

    var htmlListArray = list.map(function(r){return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
    Logger.log(htmlListArray)
    var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
    tmp.title = "My title"
    tmp.list = htmlListArray;
    //tmp.list = list.map(function(r){return r[0]; });
    return tmp.evaluate();
}
function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `include` and `doGet` functions? I think the problem might be there

Comment: Added functions

Answer (score 0):

I took me some time to find but i did it! :)
You just missed a `)` at the end of `document.addEventListener(`.
So here is a working version:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateWords).getWords();
  }) // added ')' here
  function populateWords(words){
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
    var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, {
       data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": null,
        }
     });
  }
</script>
```